# Sqlite insert last value from another table matched by id

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-design, triggers

Clearing up my question, please help or point in the right direction.

I have following example tables:

```
HistoricalValue
ID  SITEID  VAL DATE
1   1      100  9/1
2   1      120  10/1
3   2      300  10/3
4   2      350  10/10 

LOG
ID  SITEID  VAL   START_TIME    END_TIME    CALC
1     1     120      10:10      10:20       (END_TIME-START_TIME)*VAL
```

HistoricalValue table is where I enter data for each of the site, and the LOG table is where I would enter some of the parameters to calculate on.

What I want is to auto populate "VAL(ue)" column in LOG table with the last value (by id? or maybe by date) from HistoricalValue table based on the SiteID that is selected.

What is the proper way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that data entry interactive?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to allow `NULL` for *val* and fill in the true value on the fly. The following was executed in SQL Server, but little more than date manipulation will need to be changed:

```
with
HistoricalValue( ID, SiteID, Val, ValDate )as(
    select  1, 1, 100,  '2015-09-01' union all
    select  2, 1, 120,  '2015-10-01' union all
    select  3, 2, 300,  '2015-10-03' union all
    select  4, 2, 350,  '2015-10-10'
),
LogVal( ID, SiteID, Val, StartTime, EndTime )as(
    select  1, 1, 100, '2015-09-01 10:10', '2015-09-01 10:20' union all
    select  1, 1, NULL, '2015-10-01 10:10', '2015-10-01 10:20'
)
select  l.ID, l.SiteID, l.VAL LogVal, h.ValDate, h.val HistVal,
        coalesce( l.VAL, h.val ) as NewVal,
        StartTime, EndTime,
        DateDiff( SECOND, EndTime, StartTime) * coalesce( l.Val, h.Val ) as CalcVal
from    LogVal l
left join HistoricalValue h
    on  h.SiteID = l.SiteID
    and h.ValDate =(
        select  Max( ValDate )
        from    HistoricalValue
        where   SiteID = l.SiteID
            and ValDate < l.StartTime
            and Val is not null );
```

I've supplied a second Log entry with no *val* value to show how the latest value before that entry can be retrieved and used. I'm also assuming that the end and start times are actually date & time values, otherwise you can't tell which historical entries are prior to the log entry.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to do a trigger to do this automatically.  If you don't have the value when inserting, then you can do:

```
insert into example(val1)
    select val1
    from example
    order by id desc
    limit 1;
```

This assumes that `id` is an auto-incremented column and is used to determine what the "last" inserted value was.

The trigger would be a `before insert` trigger that basically runs the same code.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  Tried your suggestion, but it does not insert "last" value, into val1, I still get "NULL" value if I do not enter anything when inserting new record, but with this trigger, the id is incrementing by 2 (if last record is 10, the next record is 12 and so on)

Comment: That statements adds another row. And a BEFORE INSERT trigger would not be able to change anything that's inserted.

Comment: @andy . . . The intention is that you would use this to insert a new value based on the previous value.  If you don't have a value, use this logic.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following your suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following your suggestions.  I have a table with multiple columns (and example is simplified).   What I'm doing is keeping track of fuel consumption, so, if the value has not been supplied (meaning tank has not been topped off), then use previous value for calculation.  My problem is not knowing how to grab last value (if nothing is entered) to calculate on.  Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @andy . . . Then you should ask another question.  This question seems to be about inserting data.